# Document library error "TypeError"

Tags: 2013, document-library, error

When I click the 3 dots next to my file name in a document library I get the below pop-up.

I usually see it when I'm deleting a lot of documents. It usually goes away if I refresh the page.

Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: Something is way too wrong! Have you customised anything on the library?

Comment: Nope, it's a custom view but that's it

Comment: Can you open the developer tools in the browser and see if any errors are there?

Comment: :-/ I don't know how to do that, I don't have a lot of higher powers so I might not have permission

Comment: All you need to do is open chrome or IE, press F12 and find a tab called "Console". Try to find if there are any errors. Also try to find if network tab shows any 404 status.

Comment: Looks like this has been disabled by the IT department. I've asked them to take a look so we'll see what they think